# How to make swing dialog window on top?

Tags: java, swing

After running the following example a dialog window appears *under* the active window, for example if a browser window active at the moment than dialog appears under it. How can I make dialog window appear on top of all windows in the system?

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    frame,
    "test info",
    "test header",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
);
```

Comment: call .setVisible() on the frame first to make this visible?

Comment: Consider using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ...` instead

Comment: Please provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we also can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

before showing dialog..

```
       try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        //it will keep this frame and its dialog always on top of the other frames/windows
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            frame,
            "test info",
            "test header",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line under the frame declaration

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Thanks...